# Centering table using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that I'm wanting to make center on the screen but nothing is working. I am having trouble figuring out what I need to do or what I have done wrong. Any help would be great.

Here is my css im using:

```
<style>
table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
      }
</style>
```

Here is my code for the table:

```
<table class = 'table table-bordered '>
<tr style='background-color: black; color: white;'>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Book-Name</th>
    <th>Author-Name</th>
    <th>Edition</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Department</th>
</tr>
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr style = 'background-color: white;'>
    <td><?php echo $row['bid'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['authors'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['edition'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['quantity'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['department'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}

?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are specify the `width` of the table to `100%` which is full screen and at the same time you are using `display: block`

Two solutions:

By changing `width` to lower to full screen

By removing the `display: block` , but I have to notice that you are also setting the `height: 900px` which will make your table to 900px any ways, you could change it to `max-height`

```css
table{
    width: 80%;
    height:900px;
    overflow: auto;
     display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
      }
```

```html
<table class = 'table table-bordered '>
<tr style='background-color: black; color: white;'>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Book-Name</th>
    <th>Author-Name</th>
    <th>Edition</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Department</th>
</tr>
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr style = 'background-color: white;'>
    <td><?php echo $row['bid'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['authors'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['edition'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['quantity'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['department'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}

?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox. Using `width: 100%` with margins doesn't make sense.

```css
table {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 900px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like this:

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/cdhj7r8k/11/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result this way -->

```css
table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```